# Selecting another category from dropdown list it retains the page I'm on

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown list on my page which has 2 options. category1 and category2. This drop down has an attribute named "AutoPostBack=true". So if user selects another option the page will make a postback to the server.

I also have a gridview which fetches data from sqlDataSource. This gridview has an option "AllowPaging="true".

The problem:

GridView works fine. I can get the results from database and I also have number of pages shown. So lets say I go to page 2 in default category1. If I then select "category2" from dropdown list, then I got results from category2 but from second page.

Why is that, and how to reset so it will show records from page 1, even if I change a category from dropdown list?

So again.

User navigates to my page. By default category1 is selected. He navigates to page 2, and he gets the desired results. Then he changes his mind and wants to see category2. Page reloads, records are shown but he stays on page 2 (or whatever page he was on, before he clicked another category from dropdownlist). How to send him again to page one with category2 records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are two independent controlled that are responding to their own post back and viewstate data.

Just add an OnChange event to the DropDownList and reset the GridViews PageIndex to zero.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I've put GridView.PageIndex = 0; to SelectedIndexChanged and it works.

Answer (score 0):

you could add a button with a link to #1 and have a pull out menu with #2 info